# Python 2.7.5 Palindrome code confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i was looking around on here and i found the code for a working palindrome

```
def isPalindrome():
    string = input('Enter a string: ')
    string1 = string[::-1]
    if string[0] == string[(len(string)-1)] and string[1:(len(string)-2)] == string1[1:(len(string)-2)]:
        print('It is a palindrome')
    else:
        print('It is not a palindrome')

isPalindrome()
```

So i already changed input to raw_input. And it works.

But in the comments there was a simpler code:

```
def isPalindrome():
    string1 = input('Enter a string: ')
    string2 = string[::-1]
    if string1 == string2:
        return 'It is a palindrome'
    return 'It is not a palindrome'

isPalindrome()
```

I got the read back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\idk1.py", line 8, in <module>
    isPalindrome()
  File "C:\Python27\idk1.py", line 2, in isPalindrome
    string1 = input('Enter a string: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'racecar' is not defined
```

So i changed it to raw_input, and I wouldn't work at all. I'm curious as to why that is?

Comment: What part of your code uses `racecar`?

Comment: Is this a question for your homework?

Comment: @fdsa: He clearly tried to enter the string "`racecar`" into a Python 2 `input` prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem with copy-and-paste, my friend. You copied the source, changed variable names but forgot to check the variable use throughout the program:

```
def isPalindrome():
  string1 = input('Enter a string: ')
  string2 = string1[::-1] #notice it's string1, not string.
  if string1 == string2:
    [code]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPalindrome():
    string1 = raw_input('Enter a string: ')
    string2 = string1[::-1]
    if string1 == string2:
        return 'It is a palindrome'
    return 'It is not a palindrome'
```

In line 3, it said `string` instead of `string1`.

Comment: I continuously make these silly mistakes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me... Sorry for the previous post...

```
def isPalindrome():
string1 = raw_input('Enter a string: ')
string2 = string1[::-1]
if string1 == string2:
    return 'It is a palindrome'
return 'It is not a palindrome'

print isPalindrome()
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a string: madam
It is a palindrome
```